# Problemas con la pseudo-clase :hover y el pseudo-elmento ::before

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo un problema con unas clases que he creado, que al crear un `hover` no me cambia el color de fondo. Se trata de usar un código `ascii` en `css` que al ejecutarlo cambie. Solo puedo transformar, escalar, rotar, pero cambiar el color de la fuente no puedo.

El problema mas especifico es que he usado la propiedad `content` de `css` y quería cambiar el color del mismo código `ascii`

```css
.close::before {
    content: '\0271a';
    color: #919191;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

 .close:hover::after {
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>

<body>
   <span class="close"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo mas cercano que he hecho, es hacer otra forma y me sale uno igual pero al lado del otro. Lo que necesito es cambiar una cruz de color de gris al negro.

Os lo demuestro.

```css
.close::before {
    content: '\0271a';
    color: #919191;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close:hover::after {
    content: '\0271a';
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
 <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    </head>

    <body>
       <span class="close"></span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es hacer el `hover` tambien en `before` asi:

```css
.close::before {
    content: '\0271a';
    color: #919191;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

 .close:hover::before {
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>

<body>
   <span class="close"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias tio me estaba dando un dolor de cabeza